# Stored procedure only return the data from table 1 rather than 10 tables

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessListSQL]  
    ( --@CommaDelimitedList AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @SQLtoExecute AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @Result VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Statements TABLE
                        (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                         SQLObject NVARCHAR (MAX)
                        )

    SET @SQLtoExecute = REPLACE (@SQLtoExecute, '"', '''')
    /*================*/
    DECLARE @CommaDelimitedList  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ddd NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @R1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ddd=''

    SELECT @ddd = @ddd + organisation  + ',' 
    FROM dbo.Orgs;

    SET @CommaDelimitedList = @ddd   /*select all tables that need to be interrogated*/

    /*================*/
   INSERT INTO @Statements
       SELECT PARAM 
       FROM [dbo].[fn_MVParam](@CommaDelimitedList,',')

    DECLARE @i INT
    SELECT @i = MIN(PK) FROM @Statements

    DECLARE @max INT
    SELECT @max = MAX(PK) FROM @Statements

    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    DECLARE @Object AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
 
    WHILE @i <= @max 
    BEGIN       
        SELECT @Object = SQLObject FROM @Statements WHERE PK = @i        /*gets the table from the array table*/
        SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQLtoExecute, '{RP}', @Object)               /*replaces RP with tablename */
        -- Uncommend below to check the SQL
        -- PRINT @SQL
        DECLARE @returnstatus nvarchar(15);     /*mh did this */
        SET @returnstatus = NULL;               /*mh did this */

        EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQL,@R1=@R1
        SET @Result = @Result + @R1
        SELECT @Object = NULL
        SELECT @SQL = NULL
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

This works okay but only return the first table the tables collection come from function.

Comment: It can run in SSMS but not from MVC app because you are selecting data inside a while loop. You have to think to avoid the loop.

Comment: RBAR, why avoid looping, please check this https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/

Answer (score 0):

If I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the right answer - I need to transpose this so MVC code somehow....

```
USE [HOTFF]
GO
CREATE TABLE #Resultxx
(
   organisation varchar(max),  
   Product varchar(max)
)

DECLARE @return_value int
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR (MAX)

INSERT INTO #Resultxx 
    EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ProcessListSQL]
                          @SQLtoExecute = N'SELECT organisation, product FROM  [{rp}] WHERE category=''offers'' and Type=''free''',
                          @Result = '@Result OUTPUT'

 SELECT * FROM #Resultxx 

 DROP TABLE #Resultxx
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or clarification to the question? (In which case it should be added to the question).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can do this is call procedure A from procedure B. In procedure B insert the result into a temp table and select the temp table this then is called from MVC c# as a standard stored procedure.